# Не понимаю ошибку в framework Yii2 и JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Установил OpenServer, скачал yii2 basic, распаковал. Увидел надпись "Поздравляем". Но хром в консоли выдает:

> VM3239 storage.min.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'domains' exceeded the quota.
>       at HTMLScriptElement.a.onload (https://dl.metabar.ru/static/storage/js/storage.min.js?version=201803011320:1:6177)
>   a.onload @ VM3239 storage.min.js:1

ОС: Windows 10 64-бит.

Пожалуйста, объясните.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения в yii2. Вся проблема в стороннем файле.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте

Проблема не имеет никакого отношения к Yii2 и не влияет на его работоспособность.

Скрипт указанный в вопросе это `Яндекс.Советник`. Вероятнее всего на страницу он попал из-за какого-то плохого расширения для `Chrome`, которое добавляет этот скрипт на все страницы, чтобы получить партнерское вознаграждение. Я рекомендую отключить **все** расширения, затем включать по одному и таким образом найти расширение, которое занимается такими нехорошими делами и удалить его.

P.S. В некоторых расширениях эту "фичу" можно отключать в настройках.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Возможно у вас установлено расширение Tampermonkey в браузере , если да, то отключите его, это должно помочь.